# IntelliJ IDEA not connecting to postgres database

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea, jdbc

When trying to connect to a postgres database set up on bit.io, intelliJ throws this error

[image: error].

I am able to connect to this database via pgAdmin and used the exact same settings

Comment: pgAdmin doesn't use JDBC so you can use the "exact same settings". The [JDBC URL](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/use/#connecting-to-the-database) is wrong. It should either be `/bongo` or `/bnogodb` but not both.

Comment: Unfortunately, bit.io only lets you host a database with a name format of username/databasename. But, I believe this is not the fault of JDBC as I can connect to the database via code using a jdbc url but just not IntelliJ's built in database manager.

Answer (score 1):

`/` is valid according to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html but not all clients properly escape these characters.

The error provided is a known issue with Intellij. According to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-15968/Support-postgres-databases-with-slash-in-database-name it has been resolved and will hopefully be released soon. In the meantime, per https://docs.bit.io/docs/trouble-shooting-common-connection-issues#database-name-separator you may want to try replacing `/` with a `.`.